Is there a reason that some keys and values will not load in TOML? (Python config import)
I've set up my flask app to read my config file...
app.config.from_file("../CONFIGS/config.py", lambda f: tomllib.load(f.buffer))
f.write(str(app.config))

when I go to see the output some of the line from the config are there...
MY_VARIABLE = "1"
but
my_variable = "1"
is missing from the output...
Am I missing something?
using the 3.11 built in TOMLLIB with python 3.11

Why does your TOML file have a .py extension? And the example I see in the documentation just uses load=tomllib.load, why do you need the lambda?

I suspect the problem is that f.buffer doesn't contain the entire file, just the beginning of the file. You need to read the entire thing, e.g. tomllib.load(f.read())

In Flask, the app configuration system only picks up keys that are in uppercase, so any lowercase settings from your config file get ignored. That's why you're seeing "MY_VARIABLE" but not "my_variable".
Change your config file so that all the setting names are uppercase, like MY_VARIABLE.
(or)
Or, if you need to keep lowercase names, you can load the file yourself and manually add each setting to app.config in uppercase form.
